# How to get abi from ByteCode?

Tags: abi, bsc

How i can get ABI from source code of contract?

Comment: Your title mention abi from ByteCode while your question mention abi from source -> which one are you looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible. You might be able to get it with some sort of reverse-engineering, but in any case it probably wouldn't be easy.

Comment: I know a person who can get an abi of any contract in 5 minutes, it is possible

Comment: i easy take functions, on ethervm.io but how to convert them to json abi